# fadein fadeout callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show another select based on the previously selected value of another select. 
However, the dynamically appearing select is not showing. I used promise and data-attribute.

What should be the problem in my script?

```js
 $(function () {

        $('#masterCategory').bind('change', function () {
            var category = $(this).val();

        });

        $('select#masterCategory').bind('change', function () {
            $('label#subcategory').fadeIn();
            console.log('select[data-id="' + ($(this).val()) + '"]')
            $('select[data-id="' + ($(this).val()) + '"]').siblings().fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
                    $('select[data-id="' + ($(this).val()) + '"]').fadeIn();
                }
            );

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select Category <span>*</span></label>
<select id="masterCategory" required class="selection" name="category">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <option>Mobiles</option>
    <option>Electronics and Appliances</option>
    <option>Cars</option>
    <option>Bikes</option>
    <option>Furniture</option>
    <option>Pets</option>
    <option>Books, Sports & Hobbies</option>
    <option>Fashion</option>
    <option>Kids</option>
    <option>Services</option>
    <option>Real Estate</option>
</select>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<label id="subcategory" style="display: none">Select Sub-Category <span>*</span></label>
<div>
    <select data-id="Cars" style="display: none">
        <option href="cars.html">Commercial Vehicles</option>
        <option href="cars.html">Other Vehicles</option>
        <option href="cars.html">Spare Parts</option>
    </select>

    <select data-id="Bikes" style="display: none">
        <option href="bikes.html">Motorcycles</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Scooters</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Bicycles</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Spare Parts</option>
    </select>

    <select data-id="Furniture" style="display: none">
        <option href="furnitures.html">Sofa & Dining</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Beds & Wardrobes</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Home Decor & Garden</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Other Household Items</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Pets" style="display: none">
        <option href="pets.html">Dogs</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Aquariums</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Pet Food & Accessories</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Other Pets</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Books, Sports & Hobbies" style="display: none">
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Books & Magazines</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Musical Instruments</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Sports Equipment</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Gym & Fitness</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Other Hobbies</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Fashion" style="display: none">
        <option href="fashion.html">Clothes</option>
        <option href="fashion.html">Footwear</option>
        <option href="fashion.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Kids" style="display: none">
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Furniture And Toys</option>
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Prams & Walkers</option>
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Services" style="display: none">
        <option href="services.html">Education & Classes</option>
        <option href="services.html">Web Development</option>
        <option href="services.html">Electronics & Computer Repair</option>
        <option href="services.html">Madata-ids & Domestic Help</option>
        <option href="services.html">Health & Beauty</option>
        <option href="services.html">Movers & Packers</option>
        <option href="services.html">Drivers & Taxi</option>
        <option href="services.html">Event Services</option>
        <option href="services.html">Other Services</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Jobs" style="display: none">
        <option href="jobs.html">Customer Service</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">IT</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Online</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Marketing</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Advertising & PR</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Sales</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Clerical & Administration</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Human Resources</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Education</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Hotels & Tourism</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Accounting & Finance</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Manufacturing</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Part - Time</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Other Jobs</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Real Estate" style="display: none">
        <option href="real-estate.html">Houses</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Apartments</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">PG & Roommates</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Land & Plots</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Shops - Offices - Commercial Space</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Vacation Rentals - Guest Houses</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Mobiles" style="display: none">
        <option href="mobiles.html">Mobile phones</option>
        <option href="mobiles.html">Tablets</option>
        <option href="mobiles.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Electronics and Appliances" style="display: none">
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Computers & accessories</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Tv - vdata-ideo - audio</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Cameras & accessories</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Games & Entertainment</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Frdata-idge - AC - Washing Machine</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Kitchen & Other Appliances</option>
    </select>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$(this).val()` from within `promise().done()` where `this` refers to the scope within the done function, not the `select change` event. You could instead store the value into another variable (`val` in the example) and use that once the other elements have faded out.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#masterCategory').bind('change', function() {
    var category = $(this).val();

  });

  $('select#masterCategory').bind('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('label#subcategory').fadeIn();
    console.log('select[data-id="' + val + '"]')
    $('select[data-id="' + val + '"]').siblings().fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
      $('select[data-id="' + val + '"]').fadeIn();
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select Category <span>*</span></label>
<select id="masterCategory" required class="selection" name="category">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <option>Mobiles</option>
    <option>Electronics and Appliances</option>
    <option>Cars</option>
    <option>Bikes</option>
    <option>Furniture</option>
    <option>Pets</option>
    <option>Books, Sports & Hobbies</option>
    <option>Fashion</option>
    <option>Kids</option>
    <option>Services</option>
    <option>Real Estate</option>
</select>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<label id="subcategory" style="display: none">Select Sub-Category <span>*</span></label>
<div>
  <select data-id="Cars" style="display: none">
        <option href="cars.html">Commercial Vehicles</option>
        <option href="cars.html">Other Vehicles</option>
        <option href="cars.html">Spare Parts</option>
    </select>

  <select data-id="Bikes" style="display: none">
        <option href="bikes.html">Motorcycles</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Scooters</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Bicycles</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Spare Parts</option>
    </select>

  <select data-id="Furniture" style="display: none">
        <option href="furnitures.html">Sofa & Dining</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Beds & Wardrobes</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Home Decor & Garden</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Other Household Items</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Pets" style="display: none">
        <option href="pets.html">Dogs</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Aquariums</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Pet Food & Accessories</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Other Pets</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Books, Sports & Hobbies" style="display: none">
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Books & Magazines</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Musical Instruments</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Sports Equipment</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Gym & Fitness</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Other Hobbies</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Fashion" style="display: none">
        <option href="fashion.html">Clothes</option>
        <option href="fashion.html">Footwear</option>
        <option href="fashion.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Kids" style="display: none">
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Furniture And Toys</option>
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Prams & Walkers</option>
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Services" style="display: none">
        <option href="services.html">Education & Classes</option>
        <option href="services.html">Web Development</option>
        <option href="services.html">Electronics & Computer Repair</option>
        <option href="services.html">Madata-ids & Domestic Help</option>
        <option href="services.html">Health & Beauty</option>
        <option href="services.html">Movers & Packers</option>
        <option href="services.html">Drivers & Taxi</option>
        <option href="services.html">Event Services</option>
        <option href="services.html">Other Services</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Jobs" style="display: none">
        <option href="jobs.html">Customer Service</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">IT</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Online</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Marketing</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Advertising & PR</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Sales</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Clerical & Administration</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Human Resources</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Education</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Hotels & Tourism</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Accounting & Finance</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Manufacturing</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Part - Time</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Other Jobs</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Real Estate" style="display: none">
        <option href="real-estate.html">Houses</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Apartments</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">PG & Roommates</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Land & Plots</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Shops - Offices - Commercial Space</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Vacation Rentals - Guest Houses</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Mobiles" style="display: none">
        <option href="mobiles.html">Mobile phones</option>
        <option href="mobiles.html">Tablets</option>
        <option href="mobiles.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
  <select data-id="Electronics and Appliances" style="display: none">
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Computers & accessories</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Tv - vdata-ideo - audio</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Cameras & accessories</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Games & Entertainment</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Frdata-idge - AC - Washing Machine</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Kitchen & Other Appliances</option>
    </select>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: @charlietfl for multiple elements the fadeOut complete callback will be called each time whereas the promise approach will wait for all animations to complete. Of course we could simplify it by only fading out elements that are already visible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {

        $('#masterCategory').bind('change', function () {
            var category = $(this).val();

        });

        $('select#masterCategory').bind('change', function () {
            $('label#subcategory').fadeIn();
            var parentCategotyId=$(this).val();
            console.log('select[data-id="' + (parentCategotyId) + '"]');
            
            $('select[data-id="' + (parentCategotyId) + '"]').siblings().fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
                    $('select[data-id="' + (parentCategotyId) + '"]').fadeIn();
                }
            );

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select Category <span>*</span></label>
<select id="masterCategory" required class="selection" name="category">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <option>Mobiles</option>
    <option>Electronics and Appliances</option>
    <option>Cars</option>
    <option>Bikes</option>
    <option>Furniture</option>
    <option>Pets</option>
    <option>Books, Sports & Hobbies</option>
    <option>Fashion</option>
    <option>Kids</option>
    <option>Services</option>
    <option>Real Estate</option>
</select>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<label id="subcategory" style="display: none">Select Sub-Category <span>*</span></label>
<div>
    <select data-id="Cars" style="display: none">
        <option href="cars.html">Commercial Vehicles</option>
        <option href="cars.html">Other Vehicles</option>
        <option href="cars.html">Spare Parts</option>
    </select>

    <select data-id="Bikes" style="display: none">
        <option href="bikes.html">Motorcycles</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Scooters</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Bicycles</option>
        <option href="bikes.html">Spare Parts</option>
    </select>

    <select data-id="Furniture" style="display: none">
        <option href="furnitures.html">Sofa & Dining</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Beds & Wardrobes</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Home Decor & Garden</option>
        <option href="furnitures.html">Other Household Items</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Pets" style="display: none">
        <option href="pets.html">Dogs</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Aquariums</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Pet Food & Accessories</option>
        <option href="pets.html">Other Pets</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Books, Sports & Hobbies" style="display: none">
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Books & Magazines</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Musical Instruments</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Sports Equipment</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Gym & Fitness</option>
        <option href="books-sports-hobbies.html">Other Hobbies</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Fashion" style="display: none">
        <option href="fashion.html">Clothes</option>
        <option href="fashion.html">Footwear</option>
        <option href="fashion.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Kids" style="display: none">
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Furniture And Toys</option>
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Prams & Walkers</option>
        <option href="kdata-ids.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Services" style="display: none">
        <option href="services.html">Education & Classes</option>
        <option href="services.html">Web Development</option>
        <option href="services.html">Electronics & Computer Repair</option>
        <option href="services.html">Madata-ids & Domestic Help</option>
        <option href="services.html">Health & Beauty</option>
        <option href="services.html">Movers & Packers</option>
        <option href="services.html">Drivers & Taxi</option>
        <option href="services.html">Event Services</option>
        <option href="services.html">Other Services</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Jobs" style="display: none">
        <option href="jobs.html">Customer Service</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">IT</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Online</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Marketing</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Advertising & PR</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Sales</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Clerical & Administration</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Human Resources</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Education</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Hotels & Tourism</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Accounting & Finance</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Manufacturing</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Part - Time</option>
        <option href="jobs.html">Other Jobs</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Real Estate" style="display: none">
        <option href="real-estate.html">Houses</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Apartments</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">PG & Roommates</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Land & Plots</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Shops - Offices - Commercial Space</option>
        <option href="real-estate.html">Vacation Rentals - Guest Houses</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Mobiles" style="display: none">
        <option href="mobiles.html">Mobile phones</option>
        <option href="mobiles.html">Tablets</option>
        <option href="mobiles.html">Accessories</option>
    </select>
    <select data-id="Electronics and Appliances" style="display: none">
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Computers & accessories</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Tv - vdata-ideo - audio</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Cameras & accessories</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Games & Entertainment</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Frdata-idge - AC - Washing Machine</option>
        <option href="electronics-appliances.html">Kitchen & Other Appliances</option>
    </select>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   

</script>
```